# devSettings fro playframework 2.4

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

As the documentation says:

Using with the run command
There are a couple of special things to know about configuration when running your application with the run command.

Extra devSettings
You can configure extra settings for the run command in your build.sbt. These settings won’t be used when you deploy your application.

```
devSettings := Map("play.server.http.port" -> "8080")
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration

But when i run activator a type error is thrown:

```
Error:Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/carlos/Documents/workspace/qrsoft/manager/project
/Users/carlos/Documents/workspace/qrsoft/manager/build.sbt:27: error: not found: value devSettings
devSettings := Map("play.server.http.port" -> "8080")
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `devSettings`, you'd need to either use `PlayKeys.devSettings`, `import PlayKeys._` or `import PlayKeys.devSettings`.

To change the development mode port, the code for setting the port in the framework is:

```
System.getProperty("https.port")
```

which shows that you'd need to use the `-D` flag to specify the port, or to create the development server yourself using `NettyServer` specifying the port as a parameter.

Comment: The Play 2.4.x docs wrongly specify devSettings := `Map("play.server.http.port" -> "8080")` when it must be ` := Seq(...)` to compile.

Comment: PlayKeys.devSettings has no effect, so just as you mention: the Play 2.4.6 docs are out of sync with the code.